# Linux Router for Public IPv6 dropping packets for 27 seconds

Tags: linux, ipv6, router

I use a CentOS machine as my router at the data center. Its doesn't do any NAT. It just routes my public ips. The DC routes my blocks of ips to the WAN interface and the router passes them through to the LAN interface. All has been going well for many years using IPv4.

I recently was given a block of IPv6 addresses and I set up the same router very similarly. I can ping ipv6 on the outside from the router. I can ping ipv6 on the inside from the router. I can ping ipv6 on router from the inside.

However when I try to ping the outside from the inside it pings either 5 or 6 times and then pauses for 27 seconds. It does this over and over again. I have tried it from different machines on the inside and they all ping and pause at the exact same time. And it always pings 5 or 6 times and pauses for 27 seconds.

I have run tcpdump on the router to watch for the traffic. When I run it against the LAN interface I continually see the ping traffic trying to get through. When I run tcpdump on the WAN interface I only see the ping traffic get through when there is successful pings.

Its not just pings. I tried using wget to retrieve a ipv6 web site and same thing happens. Sometimes its successful immediately and sometimes it has to wait until the router allows it.

So something on the router is blocking ipv6 traffic for 27 seconds at a time. I have no idea what that could be. I don't think I have anything special running on it. I have turned off everything I could think of. I turned off the firewall just to check.

I do have in /etc/sysctl.conf and reloaded it:
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

Is there a problem with routing ipv4 and ipv6 at the same time? Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I checked the logs. Nothing suspicious there. ip6tables are flushed. Firewald disabled. From the inside tcpdump shows pings from the inside to both LAN and WAN but nothing during that time to the gateway or any other ipv6 outside. Something on the router is definitely blocking forwarded traffic on ipv6 only. ipv4 never gets blocked. I can also ping from the outside both WAN and LAN on the router pinging inside gets blocked for 27 seconds. I have tried on multiple devices on the inside with different ipv6 ips. They all start and stop at the same time and for the same length of time.

```
What I received from the provider:
network - 2600:xxxx:2007:1::/64
default gateway - 2600:xxxx:2007:1::1/64
2600:xxxx:2007:3::/64 has been routed to 2600:xxxx:2007:1::4

Router WAN
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 216.27.x.148  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 216.27.x.255
        inet6 fe80::20a:cdff:fe19:37c7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2600:xxxx:2007:1::4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:0a:cd:19:37:c7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1702297067  bytes 798279299679 (743.4 GiB)
        RX errors 100580  dropped 96431  overruns 34345  frame 0
        TX packets 3485200990  bytes 1240112520689 (1.1 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Router LAN
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 216.27.x.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 216.27.x.255
        inet6 2600:xxxx:2007:3::1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::6ef0:49ff:fee2:9df6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 6c:f0:49:e2:9d:f6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3682808617  bytes 1115134659583 (1.0 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5389  overruns 814  frame 814
        TX packets 1628843270  bytes 770012479669 (717.1 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 1  collisions 0



Server on the inside:
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 216.27.x.93  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 216.27.x.255
        inet6 fe80::224:1dff:fe1d:129b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2600:xxxx:2007:3::2993  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:24:1d:1d:12:9b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 57101537805  bytes 71744258917869 (65.2 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21124014770  bytes 2164291955700 (1.9 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: A router should probably have a router advertisement daemon running (such as radvd) and a few related settings. You should provide your whole configuration as well as what was given by provider, maybe there are missing parts. Feel free to obfuscate, but intelligently (there's the whole [2001:DB8::/32](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3849) you could use for this). Also this question might be suitable for https://serverfault.com/ but be sure to keep it only once if you later choose to do so.

Comment: This is definitely a weird one! Repeated predictable blackouts smell like something restarting or tripping up and reconfiguring.  Have you checked syslog? Also did you check iptables in and out of the blackouts to see if something is changing them?  In your paragraph on tcp dump you said you saw outbound (to internet) pings on LAN but then no outbound (to internet) on WAN right?  *(you proved cantos was dropping the packets?)*

Comment: I thought radvd was for auto assigning like DHCP? I am not doing that. I am statically assigning.

Comment: I set up a test lab at home and everything works as expected. I just wish I knew what was going on with this machine. I was going to replace it anyway but I hate unanswered questions.